# Translate R function caret::findCorrelation to Python 3 via Pandas using vectorisation

Tags: python, r, pandas, r-caret

The R function `caret::findCorrelation` searches a correlation matrix and returns a vector of integers corresponding to variables which, if removed, would reduce pair-wise correlations among the remaining variables. Here is the R code for this function:

```
function (x, cutoff = 0.9, verbose = FALSE, names = FALSE, exact = ncol(x) < 
100) 
 {
  if (names & is.null(colnames(x))) 
    stop("'x' must have column names when `names = TRUE`")
  out <- if (exact) 
    findCorrelation_exact(x = x, cutoff = cutoff, verbose = verbose)
  else findCorrelation_fast(x = x, cutoff = cutoff, verbose = verbose)
  out
  if (names) 
    out <- colnames(x)[out]
  out
}
```

And the function `findCorrelation_fast`, which is the one I am interested in (with optional arguments removed):

```
findCorrelation_fast <- function(x, cutoff = .90)
{
 if(any(!complete.cases(x)))
 stop("The correlation matrix has some missing values.")
 averageCorr <- colMeans(abs(x))
 averageCorr <- as.numeric(as.factor(averageCorr))
 x[lower.tri(x, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
 combsAboveCutoff <- which(abs(x) > cutoff)

 colsToCheck <- ceiling(combsAboveCutoff / nrow(x))
 rowsToCheck <- combsAboveCutoff %% nrow(x)

 colsToDiscard <- averageCorr[colsToCheck] > averageCorr[rowsToCheck]
 rowsToDiscard <- !colsToDiscard

 deletecol <- c(colsToCheck[colsToDiscard], rowsToCheck[rowsToDiscard])
 deletecol <- unique(deletecol)
 deletecol
}
```

I am writing a function that emulates the intent of this function in Python 3 with help from pandas. My implementation contains a nested `for` loop, which I understand is far from the most efficient way to achieve the desired result. The original R function does the job without any looping.

My two questions are:

1. Based on my implementation below, is there a Pythonic way to replace the nested `for` loop with a vectorised implementation?
2. Related to (1), the R function `findCorrelation_fast` uses the line
   `averageCorr <- as.numeric(as.factor(averageCorr))`. This construction seems both very alien to me and also crucial to the success of the loopless R implementation. Can anyone shed any light on what this line is doing? My intuition tells me that it is being incredibly clever and leveraging some unique behaviour of R.

My Python implementation and an example of its usage:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# calculate pair-wise correlations

def findCorrelated(corrmat, cutoff = 0.8):    

### search correlation matrix and identify pairs that if removed would reduce pair-wise correlations
# args:
    # corrmat: a correlation matrix
    # cutoff: pairwise absolute correlation cutoff
# returns:
    # variables to removed

    if(len(corrmat) != len(corrmat.columns)) : return 'Correlation matrix is not square'
    averageCorr = corrmat.abs().mean(axis = 1)

    # set lower triangle and diagonal of correlation matrix to NA
    corrmat = corrmat.where(np.triu(np.ones(corrmat.shape)).astype(np.bool))
    corrmat.values[[np.arange(len(corrmat))]*2] = None 

    # where a pairwise correlation is greater than the cutoff value, check whether mean abs.corr of a or b is greater and cut it
    to_delete = list()
    for col in range(0, len(corrmat.columns)):
        for row in range(0, len(corrmat)):
            if(corrmat.iloc[row, col] > cutoff):
                if(averageCorr.iloc[row] > averageCorr.iloc[col]): to_delete.append(row)
                else: to_delete.append(col)

    to_delete = list(set(to_delete))

    return to_delete

# generate some data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,25))

# demonstrate usage of function    
removeCols = findCorrelated(df.corr(), cutoff = 0.01) #set v.low cutoff as data is uncorrelated
print('Columns to be removed:')
print(removeCols)
uncorrelated = df.drop(df.index[removeCols], axis =1, inplace = False)
print('Uncorrelated variables:')
print(uncorrelated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Asked 4 years ago, but I'm looking for a python implementation, coming from R myself.

For 2: `as.numeric(as.factor(x))` provides the rank order of each value of x.

`as.factor()` factorizes the correlation values, assigning them levels in numerically ascending order, essentially making characters of the numbers but maintaining their relative order.

`as.numeric()` then converts the ordered levels/characters into numbers, such that the lowest value from x is now 1, and the highest is `length(unique(x))`. If there were ties, they'd have the same integer value because they would've been assigned to the same level/rank with `as.factor()`.

Note that this snippet doesn't work for matrices, only vectors.